# Installing a repo package on Ubuntu without yum installer package

Tags: apt, yum

```
Linux
Download libjpeg-turbo.repo to /etc/yum.repos.d/
sudo yum install libjpeg-turbo-official
pip install -U git+git://github.com/lilohuang/PyTurboJPEG.git
```

I am currently running Ubuntu 18.04 and I only have apt-get installation package. How do I install from the above instruction?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I almost got the full answer, but alas I'm out of time. *Yum* is for installing Red Hat/CentOS/Fedora software (and a few others). Ubuntu/Debian... uses `apt` so you just need to add repo based on Ubuntu method, and then `sudo apt update` so you can do `pip install` of the program. I've only used the `git clone` install method so might need some research if `pip install` doesn't work.

Please click [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1239767/edit) and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1239767/edit) –